# Create columns in beamer with foreach

Tags: beamer, columns, foreach, pgffor

I cannot manage to create columns with \foreach in beamer, the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\def\a {0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \foreach \x in \a {
            \column{\x\linewidth}
        }
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Throws an error:

[image: Error from the code]

Is there a solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pgffor wraps each step into a group, so you are essentially writing `{\column{.2\linewidth}}`, which beamer does not like.

Instead you can use proper `column` environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}

\def\a {0.2, 0.2, 0.2}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \foreach \x in \a {
            \begin{column}{\x\linewidth}
              test
            \end{column}
        }
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]